# How to set custom geolocations on events using Measurement Protocol? (GA4)

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-api, measurement-protocol

I would like to add custom geo-information (e.g. city) to events that are sent to our tagging server (running in AppEngine), in order to show the event location in the "real time" map view in Google Analytics Reports. The events are originating from one of our servers, so the location based on IP is not useful.

In the documentation for v1 of the Measurement Protocol, it says that you can override the computed geolocation with a request parameter "geoid" see: [UA analytics measurement protocol geoid](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#geoid), but after trying this with v2 it appears to no longer be supported (geoid is effectively ignored). I assume I need to use v2 protocol with GA4.

Is there any way to set custom locations on events so they can be visualized in the real time map view?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The measurement protocol for ga4 does not support sending location data currently.  Its actually much more limited in what we can send then the measurement protocol for UA was.

You can find information what is currently supported here [Measurement protocol ga4 events.](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference/events)